# Getting Dotenv values in envoy script in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-envoy

Typically in my Envoy.blade.php file, I first set up the variables...

```
@include('./vendor/autoload.php');

@setup
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::create(__DIR__);
    try {
        $dotenv->load();
        $dotenv->required(['DEPLOY_PATH'])->notEmpty();
    } catch ( Exception $e )  {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
@endsetup
```

When I run `envoy run deploy` I get the following error.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to
>   Dotenv\Dotenv::create() must be an instance of
>   Dotenv\Repository\RepositoryInterface, string given, called in
>   /Users/khill5/Sites/interpreter/Envoyd538ebf09581d7d4e66c810d4e2dd41c.php
>   on line 16 and defined in
>   /Users/khill5/Sites/interpreter/vendor/vlucas/phpdotenv/src/Dotenv.php:62

What has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
@setup
    $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);
    try {
        $dotenv->load();
        $dotenv->required(['DEPLOY_PATH'])->notEmpty();
    } catch ( Exception $e )  {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
@endsetup
```